# extra entities with nil attributes in Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Here is my code. I have extra entities with nil attributes in Core Data. when I delete and run application firstly, I get one saved object with nil attributes fetched from core data.

```
class RepositoryEntity {

private var context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

func fetchRepositories() -> [RepositoryEntity] {
    do {
        return try context.fetch(RepositoryEntity.fetchRequest())
    } catch(let error) {
        print("errr: ", error.localizedDescription)
    }
    return []
}

func saveObject(repo: Repository, onSuccess: () -> Void, onFailure: (_ error: String) -> Void) {
        let repoEntity = RepositoryEntity(context: self.context)
        repoEntity.fullName = repo.fullName
        repoEntity.dateCreated = repo.dateCreated
        repoEntity.url = repo.url
        repoEntity.language = repo.language
        repoEntity.repoDescription = repo.repoDescription
        repoEntity.id = repo.id

        let ownerEntity = OwnerEntity(context: self.context)
        ownerEntity.ownerName = repo.owner.ownerName
        ownerEntity.avatarUrl = repo.owner.avatarUrl

        repoEntity.addToOwner(ownerEntity)
        
//        Save the data
        do {
            try context.save()
            onSuccess()
        } catch(let error) {
            onFailure("Something Happend. Try again later.")
            print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}

func deleteRepository(repo: Repository, onSuccess: () -> Void, onFailure: (_ error: String) -> Void) {
   
    let repositories = fetchRepositories()
    guard let deletableRepo = repositories.first(where: {$0.id == repo.id}) else { return }

    self.context.delete(deletableRepo)
    
    do {
        try context.save()
        onSuccess()
    } catch(let error) {
        onFailure("Something Happens. try again later.")
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    
}
```

}

when I delete and run application firstly, I get one saved object with nil attributes fetched from core data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write "I get one saved object...": what object? `RepositoryEntity`? How do you know you have a saved object, by calling `fetchRepositories()`? I can only assume it's like that (as opposed to having an empty `OwnerEntity`).

In that case, the problem is that, to call `func fetchRepositories()` you need to create an instance. So, when you start with zero objects, as soon as you call `fetchRepositories()` you already have at least one.

Change:

```
func fetchRepositories() -> [RepositoryEntity]
```

with:

```
static func fetchRepositories() -> [RepositoryEntity]
```

and call it from the type:

```
RepositoryEntity.fetchRepositories()
```

The same also for `deleteRepository`.

Comment: Yes, I get 

`<RepositoryEntity: 0x60000361ccd0> (entity: RepositoryEntity; id: 0x60000155c900 <x-coredata:///RepositoryEntity/tA2987358-101B-4097-8A50-C4AA26178CBE2>; data: {
    dateCreated = nil;
    fullName = nil;
    id = 0;
    language = nil;
    owner =     (
    );
    repoDescription = nil;
    url = nil;
})`

Comment: My problem is solved. thanks, but can you explain more deeply why I had problem when I was using funcs without static keyword. At this moment RepositoryEntity object is not created because of static keyword but when RepositoryEntity object was created what was happening, why was happening this problem ?

Comment: @RezoJoglidze, `static` functions are "type functions", they are valid for all objects of that type. Say you have a struct "Car" with a function `price()`: that function sets the price for a specific car, and each car can have a different price. So, when you call `price()`, you **must** have a "Car" object. If you have `static price()`, you can change the price list, so *any* car will have that same price - even when there are no cars.

Comment: @RezoJoglidze, Without `static` you need to create a car to set its price: in your case, a `RepositoryEntity` was created so you could fetch the repositories. For more info: [Swift docs](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html).